# Llenar textbox desde base de datos sql con LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Quisiera saber como puedo llenar varios textbox desde una consulta linq, quiero que desde un método se imprima en los textbox los datos que tengo en mi base de datos

```
public void Todo()
    {
        var Contacto = (from i in dc.Persona
                        where i.cedula== int.Parse(ddlcedula.SelectedValue)
                        select new
                        {
                            i.primernombre,
                            i.segundonombre,
                            i.primerapellido,
                            i.segundoapellido,
                            i.telefono

                        }).FirstOrDefault();

        pnombre.Text = Contacto.primernombre.ToString();
        snombre.Text = Contacto.segundonombre.ToString();
        papellido.Text = Contacto.primerapellido.ToString();
        sapellido.Text = Contacto.segundoapellido.ToString();
        telefono.Text = Contacto.telefono.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Y el problema donde esta? por lo que veo lo estas haciendo

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que te crees una clase DTO para Contacto (En tu caso) y Bindees las propiedades que necesites en los TextBox en cuestión. Un ejemplo sería que tuvieses un 
**ContactoDTO** con parametros : - *Nombre*, - *Apellidos*, - *Teléfono*.

y en el XAML en el textbox en cuestión deberías tener algo tal que así:

```
<Textbox
Text="{Binding Contacto.Nombre, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
<Textbox
Text="{Binding Contacto.Nombre, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
<Textbox
Text="{Binding Contacto.Nombre, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

De esta forma cuando cargues el objeto de ContactoDTO, ya tendrás todos los campos en sus respectivos Textboxes. Para poder usar esto, después de llamar con LINQ a la DDBB tendrás que crearte un método que te genere un new ContactoDTO y te rellene campo a campo. Para cualquier problema le echamos un vistazo al código; un saludo.